# Include code from jQuery load() onto page source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I am currently using the below to include a header and a footer on every page.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#header").load("https://example.com/modules/header.html");
        $("#footer").load("https://example.com/modules/footer.html");
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the code on header and footer isn't being included in the source code of the page, so text crawlers like Textise can't see the header or footer content.

[image: source code view]

How can I push the code of header and footer to be included in the loaded pages' source code?

I tried the php below in comments but no luck either.

Comment: By using a server side rendering system like PHP to include the footer and header in each page.

Comment: I tried php but I'm having issues getting it to work.  
 https://weareoneliving.com/php/index.php Server php is 7.4. In htaccess I have this
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wBmVUZg9agxH5C-ohXh5MsV0d74ck2OeqbiP-HeINFo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And this on index.php  

<div id="header"><?php include("https://weareoneliving.com/php/modules/header.php"); ?></div>